# binding UDP socket to multiple ports

Tags: java, c, udp, multicast

Can I bind UDP socket on multiple ports?

I know answer can be NO, but I need this.

I have more than one UDP (multicast) streams on different ports to receive, and I want order of receiving packets between different streams to be same order packets reached to NIC.

With socket binding to each port seems impossible, because the order of reading packets from streams will depend on UDP receive buffers and how threads executed to receive packets from different streams.

I am looking for solution in Java, but if possible in C only, I will switch to that.

Please help me on this.

**EDIT**

The order I need, because I am developing application on MPEG TS (H.222), which will remultiplex TS streams received from different multicasts to single stream (MPTS) and then re-transmits as single stream. And I want mixing packets from different streams to be in very accurate order, with very few going out of order.

If I capture packets from multiple multicasts in order they reached to NIC, I can get accurate order, with very few going out of order due to intermediate jitters from source to my application. Very few going out of order is not problem. And all multicast sources and my application is in LAN only.

When multicast streams are of low rate, say around 20 Mbps, everything working fine. But when multicast streams are very high rate, say more than 50 Mbps, some receiver thread may be idle due to CPU even if it has packets to take from UDP. And when thread goes idle for say around 50 ms, with 60 Mbps, in 50 ms there will be lot of data, which will create gaps for that time from that stream in final queue.

Comment: You did answer your own question. It's not possible in Java, nor in C. The functionality to order the packets based on the order they arrived at the NIC does not exists in the IP stack or the socket API. This is normally handled by including a sequence number in the payload, and reordering packets based on that.

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the packet ordering? That's not what UDP is for.

Answer (score 0):

Java and C have nothing to do with it. It's not possible. A socket represents an endpoint bound to a single local port. Period.

It's also difficult to see how it would solve your problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a socket to multiple ports.  However, you can set the `SO_TIMESTAMP` socket option on your sockets, which will enable the kernel sending an ancillary control message containing the reception time of the last packet read on that socket.